# Is there any way I can run Debian Bookworm on my BL131DL in Userland app?

Tags: android

on my 32-bit android OS on BL131DL, Debian installs as version Bullseye, and upgrade to current "stable" Bookworm segfaults on installation of libc6 version 2.36-9. Ubuntu installs jammy release with libc6 version 2.35.  Is there any workaround to allow bookworm libc6 to run?